# expression evaluator in scala (with maybe placeholders?)

Tags: regex, scala

I am reading something like this from my configuration file :

```
metric1.critical = "<2000 || >20000"
metric1.okay = "=1"
metric1.warning = "<=3000"
metric2.okay = ">0.9 && < 1.1 "
metric3.warning ="( >0.9 && <1.5) || (<500 &&>200)"
```

and I have a

```
metric1.value =  //have some value
```

My aim is to basically evaluate

```
    if(metric1.value<2000 || metric1.value > 20000)
     metric1.setAlert("critical");
    else if(metric1.value=1)
     metric.setAlert("okay");
    //and so on
```

I am not really good with regex so I am going to try not to use it. I am coding in Scala and wanted to know if any existing library can help with this. Maybe i need to put placeholders to fill in the blanks and then evaluate the expression? But how do I evaluate the expression most efficiently and with less overhead?

EDIT:
In java how we have expression evaluator Libraries i was hoping i could find something similar for my code . Maybe I can add placeholders in the config file like "?" these to substitute my metric1.value (read variables) and then use an evaluator?
OR
Can someone suggest a good regex for this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Parser combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) is the best solution here. See [this example for your problem](http://pastebin.com/2Ty3XWg8). Also there is [Eval in twitter util library](https://github.com/twitter/util#eval), but I can't recommend it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like you want to define your own syntax using a parser combinator library.

There is a parser combinator built into the scala class library. Since the scala library has been modularized, it is now a separate project that lives at https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators.

Update: everybody looking for a parser combinator library that is conceptually similar to scala-parser-combinators should take a look at [fastparse](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse). It is very fast, and does not use macros. So it can serve as a drop-in replacement for scala-parser-combinators.

There are some examples on how to use it in [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed), Chapter 33, "Combinator Parsing".

Here is a little grammar, ast and evaluator to get you started. This is missing a lot of things such as whitespace handling, operator priority etc. You should also not use strings for encoding the different comparison operators. But I think with this and the chapter from Programming in Scala you should be able to come up with something that suits your needs.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.{JavaTokenParsers, PackratParsers}

sealed abstract class AST
sealed abstract class BooleanExpression extends AST
case class BooleanOperation(op: String, lhs: BooleanExpression, rhs:BooleanExpression) extends BooleanExpression
case class Comparison(op:String, rhs:Constant) extends BooleanExpression
case class Constant(value: Double) extends AST

object ConditionParser extends JavaTokenParsers with PackratParsers {

  val booleanOperator : PackratParser[String] = literal("||") | literal("&&")
  val comparisonOperator : PackratParser[String] = literal("<=") | literal(">=") | literal("==") | literal("!=") | literal("<") | literal(">")
  val constant : PackratParser[Constant] = floatingPointNumber.^^ { x => Constant(x.toDouble) }
  val comparison : PackratParser[Comparison] = (comparisonOperator ~ constant) ^^ { case op ~ rhs => Comparison(op, rhs) }
  lazy val p1 : PackratParser[BooleanExpression] = booleanOperation | comparison
  val booleanOperation = (p1 ~ booleanOperator ~ p1) ^^ { case lhs ~ op ~ rhs => BooleanOperation(op, lhs, rhs) }
}

object Evaluator {

  def evaluate(expression:BooleanExpression, value:Double) : Boolean = expression match {
    case Comparison("<=", Constant(c)) => value <= c
    case Comparison(">=", Constant(c)) => value >= c
    case Comparison("==", Constant(c)) => value == c
    case Comparison("!=", Constant(c)) => value != c
    case Comparison("<", Constant(c)) => value < c
    case Comparison(">", Constant(c)) => value > c
    case BooleanOperation("||", a, b) => evaluate(a, value) || evaluate(b, value)
    case BooleanOperation("&&", a, b) => evaluate(a, value) && evaluate(b, value)
  }
}

object Test extends App {

  def parse(text:String) : BooleanExpression = ConditionParser.parseAll(ConditionParser.p1, text).get

  val texts = Seq(
    "<2000",
    "<2000||>20000",
    "==1",
    "<=3000",
    ">0.9&&<1.1")

  val xs = Seq(0.0, 1.0, 100000.0)

  for {
    text <- texts
    expression = parse(text)
    x <- xs
    result = Evaluator.evaluate(expression, x)
  } {
    println(s"$text $expression $x $result")
  }
}
```

Comment: Parser combinators library is not the part of scala library any more (at least in some cases). It could be useful to add [this link](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) to your answer.

Comment: The problem is I dont have enough time to write a Parser. I was hoping to find a library for the same. I guess none exist to your knwoledge ? :\

Comment: For standard expressions like e.g. (x<10) || (x>100) you could just reuse an existing parser or grammar. But the syntax you want is a bit non-standard. So obviously there is no existing library. But writing a parser in Scala is pretty easy and also great fun and a good way to learn. The most work is thinking about what grammar you want. And that is independent of the language/framework you use to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Scala has built in Interpreter library which you can use. The library provides functionalities similar to `eval()` in many other languages. You can pass Scala code snippet as String to the `.interpret` method and it will evaluate it.

```
import scala.tools.nsc.{ Interpreter, Settings }

val settings = new Settings   
settings.usejavacp.value = true
val in = new Interpreter(settings) 
val lowerCritical = "<2000" // set the value from config
val value = 200   
in.interpret(s"$value $lowerCritical")                    //> res0: Boolean = true
val value1 = 20000                               //> value1  : Int = 20000
in.interpret(s"$value1 $lowerCritical")          //> res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Interpreter is deprecated now

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an actual parser for this.

Most answers are suggesting Scala's parser combinators, and that's a perfectly valid choice, if a bit out-of-date.

I'd suggest [Parboiled2](http://parboiled2.org), an other parser combinator implementation that has the distinct advantage of being written as Scala macros - without getting too technical, it means your parser is generated at compile time rather than runtime, which can yield significant performance improvements. Some benchmarks have Parboiled2 up to 200 times as fast as Scala's parser combinator.

And since parser combinators are now in a separate dependency (as of 2.11, I believe), there really is no good reason to prefer them to Parboiled2.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem and I ended up writing my own expression evaluation library [scalexpr](https://github.com/virsox/scalexpr). It is a simple library but it can validate / evaluate expressions that are similar to the ones in the question. You can do things like:

```
val ctx = Map("id" -> 10L, "name" -> "sensor1")
val parser = ExpressionParser()
val expr = parser.parseBooleanExpression(""" id == 10L || name == "sensor1" """).get
println(expr3.resolve(ctx3)) // prints true
```

If you don't want to use the library, I recommend the [fastparse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/#ExampleParsers) parser... It is much faster than parser combinators, a little bit slower than parboiled, but much easier to use than both.

Comment: from @Newion : The recent version of scalexpr is available as fork: https://github.com/pawelkaczor/scalexpr